# Grails: reusing an action

Tags: grails

I'm building an application that among other things allows users to upload documents. I have the basic create/view actions working just fine, but i'd like to reuse this action in other places.

I want to know if anyone has a pointer for how to do this. There doesn't seem to be a very good way of doing this.

Here are a few ways i've considered:

1. Try to do a chain(). This doesn't work since chaining does a GET, and to upload you need a POST.
2. Break out the main business logic into the Grails "service", and make two actions that use the same code.
3. Use a JS modal window. I've been thinking a modal that contains an iframe to an "unskinned" version of the document upload. The trick here is to get the window to close when the upload is done.

Thanks

--Matthias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't care for the extending controller method.  In fact, I avoid inheritance when possible.  I'd rather put the common code in a service class and reuse it that way.

Comment: I've been trying this out... but in order to get the file off the request stream i needed to make the API like this "def Document saveDocument(request, params)". What's interesting is since the place that i'm trying to reuse this logic is in a webform, it looks like the "request" objects are different. In the regular CRUD controller it is a org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest (which has a "getFile()" method), while from the webflow i get a org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest object... I guess i'll try to figure that one out.

Comment: Akk... I got this "wrong HTTPServletRequest" issue to work. I was nesting two <form> tags together. So the file wasn't being uploaded with the ***enctype="multipart/form-data"*** param

Answer (score 1):

You can use a base controller class, and place the common functionality there. Then extend the base controller and call the method from other action methods.

Comment: My answer was not to suggest this is a bad way.  Merely to give another option.

Comment: Yea... This solution is valid too. The trick is how to do this going forward. If there are lots of these "shared" actions then the base class get's unwieldy. Thanks though.